# How to control a piezoelectric actuator programmatically?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, amplifier, actuator

How can one control a piezoelectric actuator programmatically (e.g. with a 3.3. Volt digital signal from a Raspberry Pi or any other method you recommend)? The goal is to be able to output an arbitrary signal (0-220 Volts +/-5% , 0-10 kHz frequency +/-5% to derive a piezo. My signal contains high AND low frequencies that are both important.

I appreciate any links to YouTube, articles, and component products, datasheets since I'm new to circuits (physics background here). Compactness is very important but the output signal doesn't have to be linear (as long as I can map an input to a known output). I cannot use PWM since the output signal shouldn't contain unwanted frequencies.

Comment: Sorry, I see two questions there, one about Christmas lights, another about a piezoelectric actuator. For both, what will determine how to control it depends largely on their own specs (i.e. some lights will be fine if you PWM them at a 0~10kHz frequency as you propose, some wont even turn on, some will flicker like crazy, etc). So as it stands it's impossible to answer your question precisely.

Comment: My point being, that not necessarily you will be able to translate what you learn with christmas lights into something usable with your piezo actuator. And the less clear you are about either will make this harder to answer.

Comment: That said, there are opto isolated solid state relays which you can control with a RPi though. Not sure if they can be driven at 10kHz but its a start for generic 220V AC loads.

Comment: Addressable LEDs in your picture don't use 220v, they run off of 5v logic, so just a simple 3.3v->5v level shifter is needed.

Comment: @WesleyLee The main question is piezoelectric actuators. I cannot do this with PWM since I'm not trying to control power. I want to generate a high voltage signal controlled programmatically and thought to add a little holiday sprit to it.

Comment: I'm reading about solid state relays and they might be what I'm looking for. Can I use them to generate intermediate states or is it just on and off?

Comment: wow, that video is very annoying ... just a trigger for an epileptic seizure ... are you absolutely certain that you want your lights to exhibit that behavior?

Comment: It is one question now.